# Mocha test error when testing code with jquery promise

Tags: javascript, tdd, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to test following code. Basically server rejects this request since some parameter were not sent as required by api specification.
`Api.createRecord` use `jquery.ajax` under the hood and returns a `jquery` promise when called.

```
describe("Creating test record with incorrect data", ()=> {
    const params      = {tId:"12323","col":"colValue"};
    it('Should not create new record', (done) => {
        const result = Api.createRecord(params);
        console.log(result);
        expect(result)
            .to.eventually.equal(null)
            .notify(done);
    });
});
```

When I run this code I get following error.

```
  Error: done() invoked with non-Error: {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"SyntaxError"}
      at mightThrow (node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3583:29)
      at Window.process (node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3651:12)
      at Timeout.callback [as _onTimeout] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:524:19)
```

I am not able to find out what is the problem. Whether there is some problem in my code or somewhere else.

This is how I am sending ajax request.

```
sendRequest(URL, dataToSend) {
    return $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : URL,
        crossDomain : true,
        data        : JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
        dataType    : 'json'
    }).fail((responseData) => {
        if (responseData.responseCode) {
            console.error(responseData.responseCode);
        }
    });
},
```

is there some problem in above code that it handles failures instead of it getting thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after reading mocha docs carefully I found the solution.

> In Mocha v3.0.0 and newer, returning a Promise and calling done() will
>   result in an exception, as this is generally a mistake:

```
const assert = require('assert');

it('should complete this test', function (done) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    assert.ok(true);
    resolve();
  })
    .then(done);
});
```

I changed my test case to this one and it worked.

```
expect(result).to.be.rejected;
```